# How do I use tabs instead of spaces in Aptana Studio?

Tags: aptana

The tab key is inserting spaces when I'm editing PHP files. How can I insert tabs instead?

I've checked that Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > "Insert spaces for tabs" is cleared.

I'm using Aptana Studio 3.0.7 standalone on Windows 7.

Comment: @Jon No, but it involves programming software tools, which the [faq] says is on-topic.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The PHP editor can override the global settings. Try:

Preferences > Aptana Studio > Editors > PHP > Indentation

Select **Use Tabs** for Tab policy